# How do I communicate between a server and a client using sockets? [C]

Tags: c, unix, tcp

I am doing a Unix, C assignment. I am creating a Server and a Client which will interact with each other. I am pretty sure I have set up the basic framework but I when I try to send/receive messages, it doesn't work.

Here is the while loop code for the server, I tried to show only the relevant code:

```
while(1) {
            clntAdrLen = sizeof(clntAddr);
            clntFd = accept(srvrFd, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, NULL);
            if (fork() == 0) { 
                    send(clntFd, "YourMessage", 12, NULL);
                    close(clntFd);
                    exit(0);
            } else {
                    close(clntFd);
            }
}
```

And here is the code for client:

```
do {
            result = connect(srvrFd, (struct sockaddr*)&srvrAddr, srvrLen);
            if(result==-1) {
                    sleep(1);
            }
            recv(srvrFd, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL);
            printf("%s", buf); //here I try to print the message sent by server
    } while (result==1);
```

When I run both server and client, It should print "YourMessage". Instead it prints:

```
N0�,
```

Am I just doing it wrong? Thanks

Comment: can you print the value of clntFd?

Comment: Oh man, it prints "-1". Not good. Do you think this is a problem from the client?

Comment: yup. That is the core of all your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is in accept function.

As said in Linux Programmer's Manual:

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to  by  addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I think I accidentally changed it to NULL when I was messing with the send function. It works correctly now thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Do yourself a favor and buy yourself "UNIX Network Programming"  ISBN-10: 0139498761

There is way more to socket programming than meets the eye.

For one, how are you going to know on the receiving end how long the sent string is? Are you going to presume it's always 12, in most practical examples it won't be the same every time.

Are you going to read until you hit an end of string, or are you going to send an integer at the start to tell the reader what the length is?

If you use an integer do you know about endian-ness?

Are you really going to learn anything if we do your homework for you? Presumably you're in college and paying your tuition. Are you there to pass or are you there to learn?